# populate combobox with enum value

Tags: c#, winforms

On form load (edit action) I want to combobox be selected with appropriate value. These value is of type LangEnum.

I tried with `comboBoxLanguage.SelectedValue = book.Language;` but combo is always populated with default value (first from enum list).

update:

book.Language is declared as

`public enum EnumLang { English = 1, German = 2, Other = 3 };`

I tried both with

```
comboBoxLang.SelectedItem = (Book.EnumLang)book.Language;
```

and with

```
comboBoxLang.SelectedItem = book.Language;
```

and nothing works (default first value (English) is always set) and worth to mention is that on debug mode book.Language is set To German or Other but English is selected on combobox.

Comment: What is the `value-member` of your combo?

Comment: You say you are trying to set the value of your combobox inside the `Load` event of your Form. Have you tried to set the combobox item in another point of your code? For example inside the `Shown` event of the Form or just after the `InitializeComponent()` method call inside the Constructor of the Form?

Answer (score 1):

That looks right to me!
I am doing the same thing, are you sure that `book.Language` string is an EXACT match to one of the items in the list?

And is the list populated BEFORE you are trying to `SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 0):

Better try:

```
comboBoxLanguage.SelectedItem = book.Language;

// or even

comboBoxLanguage.Text = book.Language.ToString(); //should work
```

You might want to set the `ValueMember` property to get or set the `SelectedValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me using SelectedItem:

```
comboBoxLanguage.SelectedItem = book.Language;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell what kind of variable `book` is: is it of type `LangEnum`? Or is it a class with a `Language` property? (in this last case: what is the type of the `Language` property?)

If `book` is of type `LangEnum` you can use the `SelectedItem` property as others have said. (Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue) if you need more informations of the differences between the two combobox properties)
Otherwise you'll probably need a cast:

`comboBoxLanguage.SelectedItem = (LangEnum)book.Language;`

Moreover, if you are populating your combobox inside a WinForm event, you should also care about the order in which they are fired. Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070163/order-of-events-form-load-form-shown-and-form-activated-in-windows-forms) form more infos.