# Windows Forms - optimize painting

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have a small child form (dialog) in my c# application that loads the available printers on the machine/network into a listbox in the Load event, and in the Shown event selects the one in the list that is the Default printer

Trouble is, even though there are only about 8 available printers there is still a noticable load time of a second or two, so I'm thinking that mycode is wrong.

here is my code (taken from another post on StackOverFlow about getting/setting the default printer):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    private void frmPrinters_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        foreach (string printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            settings.PrinterName = printer;
            if (settings.IsDefaultPrinter)
            {
                this.lstAvailablePrinters.SelectedItem = printer;
            }
        }

    }

    private void frmPrinters_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> lstOfPrinters = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
        {
            this.lstAvailablePrinters.Items.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        //listAllPrinters();

    }

public static class myPrinters
{
    [DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
}
```

is there some different way to handle this, or better way, or what am I doing wrong?

thanks
Philip

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows the (simplified) order of event to be: Load, Activated, Shown. (Unless you mess it up - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070163/order-of-events-form-load-form-shown-and-form-activated-in-windows-forms).) So you should try to __move all the code__ to the `Shown` event. Also displaying a Waitcursor will give the user the secure feeling, that the machine is working for him or her.

Comment: @TaW `displaying a Waitcursor will give the user the secure feeling` - not really. blocking the UI thread for a number of seconds causes Windows to label your application as "Not Responding..". The right approach from a UX standpoint is to do stuff in a background thread and show a loading overlay over your UI,  while disabling controls to prevent the user from re-firing the job, but keeping the UI thread free.

Comment: 1) OP was talking a bout __one second or two__  2) Not blocking the UI thread makes sense if the user can actually do anything, which here, obviously, is not the case  3) The WaitCursor is normal, a loading overlay is also OK.

Comment: @TaW I don't buy that for a second.  Anything that can take time should be on a background thread.  Two seconds on my machine is usually 10 on my clients'.

Comment: I never even considered a background worker, but of course, that's what they're for... will give that a loo.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't do anything about the fact that retrieving `InstalledPrinters` or Calling `SetDefaultPrinter` is slow. However what you should do is execute any slow code asynchronously in order to avoid blocking the UI thread.

First you can detect which code is slow using the `Stopwatch` class.

Secondly, you can use a [BackgroundWorker](http://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive) or something else to execute the slow code.