# How to reload the data grid view during runtime c#

Tags: c#, forms, datatable, datagridview, application-restart

I have reload the data for `data grid view` each time the `form` open.

```
 Student_DetailEntities db = new Student_DetailEntities();
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     db.StudentTables.Load();
     studentTableBindingSource.DataSource = db.StudentTables.Local;
 }
```

To ensure the `data table` is `refresh` and `show` in `data grid view`, I have tried this code

```
private void refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Application.Restart();
        Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

and I try

```
private void refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

But the `data grid view` still `not reload`. Each time I `add` new `item`, I need to `close` and `open` the `form` again for it to show in `data grid view`.

Comment: How do you open `form1`?

Comment: When I run the program, it will open form1 which contain the data grid view. The other form to add the new item is open only if the user click menu strip on form1

Comment: You should put the code of  `Form1_Load` in `refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click`

Comment: I have tried it. But it just make it redundant. Another menu strip showing up under the previous menu strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  use [`Shown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) event instead of `Form.Load`.So that you can reload the data each time the form is shown.

```
Student_DetailEntities db = new Student_DetailEntities();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shown += Form1_Shown; 
}
 
 
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     db.StudentTables.Load();
     studentTableBindingSource.DataSource = db.StudentTables.Local;
}
```

See the detail of `Form.Load`, `Form.Shown`:

[Order of events 'Form.Load', 'Form.Shown' and 'Form.Activated' in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070163/order-of-events-form-load-form-shown-and-form-activated-in-windows-forms)

**@Caius Jard** pointed out in comments, you can simply add  `Form.Shown` event handler by "Form Designer --> Properties --> Events --> double click Shown then add code" instead of `Shown += Form1_Shown;` in `Form1_Load` that I mentioned above.

Comment: You are right. I have added your suggestion as well. Thanks for contribution

Comment: I have added the `form_1_shown` and `form_1_load` as you show above. But when I do `application.restart`, it still not reload. The data grid view still showing same result.

Comment: You don't need to `Application.Restart` just try to use [`ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) .

Comment: Do u mean I use 
            `Form f = new Form(); f.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK; `
 under `refreshToolStripMenuItem_Click`?

Comment: It depends what you want, You can use ShowDialog  as `Form f = new Form(); f.ShowDialog();` or you can use `var f = new Form(); f.Show();`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965043/how-to-open-a-new-form-from-another-form

Comment: I think it is not working. It just pop up a new form, without reloading the grid view

Comment: Put debugger the entrance of `Form1_Shown`. See if method is fired when you open the form.